# Prevent googlebot from indexing other domains on same hosting account

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, hosting, googlebot

I have a hosting account which is used to host 3 websites.
All 3 websites are independent of each other.

The hosting account is linked to main domain .lets call it www.maindomain.com and the files of this website are on the root of the hosting.

the other two domains www.domainA.com and www.domainB.com are linked to subfolders domainA and domainB respectively.

google shows www.maindomain.com/domainA and www.maindomain.com/domainB in search results of maindomain.com even though domainA and domainB have nothing to do with that website except the fact that they are hosted in same hosting account.

How can I prevent googlebot from indexing domainA and domainB subfolders when crawling maindomain.com .
Can I used robots.txt and prevent subfolder crawling (but will it stop google from indexing www.domainA and www.domainB as a separate entity?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming domainA and domainB are set up using the corresponding subfolders as document roots, you might define [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) in your main domain as

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /domainA/
Disallow: /domainB/
```

To exclude only Googlebot and allow all others

```
User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: /domainA/
Disallow: /domainB/
```

---

But keep in mind, that it seems the domains aren't linked by full URLs like `http://domaina.com/some/path`, but rather `/domainA/some/path`.

You could prevent crawling in the first place by substituting the `href`s with full qualified URLs.